# WPF Install Setup and Deployment and sql Script file

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, visual-studio-2013, deployment

I'm currently developing a small WPF application.
I generate sql script file that contains commands to create database and tables, views, procedures and so on.
But where in my wpf code I must put this script or how to read the sql script file during first run and create database and tables? Other if the client choose a diferente folder and directory to install the application how to get a path of sql script file? I use Visual Studio Installer.

```
void excuteScript()
        {


            String connString = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
            String cmdText = "select * from master.dbo.sysdatabases where name= 'Teste'";
            Boolean bRet;

            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connString);
            SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, sqlConnection);
            try
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                bRet = reader.HasRows;
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                bRet = false;
                sqlConnection.Close();
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }

            if (bRet == true)
            {


            }
            else
            {
                string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";

                var file = new FileInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"teste.sql"));
                string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
                Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
                server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);

            }

        }
```

Comment: Hi, first of all, can you give us an idea which sql are you using? are you using a SQL server? or SQLite? Are you using some kind of ORM like entity framework or sqlite-net?

Comment: @LawrenceA.Contreras i'm using SQL Server. And not using ORM.

Comment: The reason I asked if you're using any sort of ORM, the Entity Framework has a Seed method that allows you to specify initial data. However, since you're generating a sql script, why not just execute it outside of your application?

Comment: @LawrenceA.Contreras Outside of my application is not good for my clients. It must be automatic during first execution.

Comment: Well since it's inside your application you have all the freedowm to write all the logic to install those script. What you need is to identify if you already did ran the script or not. Now when you're running the script from within your app, then the location of the sql script should be relative.

Comment: @LawrenceA.Contreras see my code above. It works but i don't know if is a good practices use it.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that.

Comment: @LawrenceA.Contreras in visual studio its run fine, but when I generate exe and run it doesn't works the message is: `Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.`

Comment: @LawrenceA.Contreras is mdf a good solution how to use it?